# Make div inside li with list-style-position: inside appear to the right of number

Tags: html, css

This looks like a very simple thing, but I just could not find a solution online.
I want to make the div appear to the right of the number while keeping the number inside `li`.

```css
ol {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

li {
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>
  <div>
  !!!text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  </div>
</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div tag is a block element, You should use a span element instead, which is inline.

```css
ol {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

li {
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>
  <span>
  !!!text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  </span>
</li>
</ol>
```

If you really want to use div, add `style="display: inline"`

```css
ol {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

li {
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
   div{
display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>
  <div>
  !!!text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  </div>
</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

To align text after the number either use the span tag as it is an inline container in html else define the display inline property with div to align the text after the number

```html
<ol>
<li>
  <span>
  !!!text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  </span>
</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also set the inside div display to contents

```
display: contents
```